# How can I resolve "MSBuild error ; CA0001" while running code analysis?

Tags: c#, powershell, msbuild, continuous-integration, fxcop

I am just adding FxCop ruleset in my project and then run the code analysis, my project gets failed with some errors. One of the main error is:

> "MSBUILD : error : CA0001 : The following error was encountered while reading module 'MyProject': Could not resolve type reference: [System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]System.Func`2."

Is there any possibility to resolve the errors while running the code analysis? I am running my project in "Windows PowerShell."

And also I am getting the error like:

> "MSBUILD : error : CA0001 : Rule=Microsoft.Interoperability#CA1404, Target= MyMethod: Signature is not valid."

Comment: Whether the issue was resolved for you , or still facing this issue?